# Oracle RMAN Status

Tags: oracle, rman

I was just hoping someone could give me home help in understanding this, as I've not found any good information.

There is a view: v$rman_status. After our nightly backup, a report is generated from there. I have pasted a clip below.

```
SESSION ID  OPERATION   STEP    STATUS
195918  RMAN        COMPLETED
195899  RMAN        COMPLETED
195840  DELETE      COMPLETED
195916  RMAN        RUNNING
195893  RMAN        COMPLETED
195858  BACKUP  CONTROLFILE COMPLETED
195863  BACKUP  SPFILE  COMPLETED
```

What does any of this really tell me? Of course if the status of any is FAILED, then there is an issue. But I want to know if any of this information is useful to us. Multiple session ID's, multiple RMAN / BACKUP / COMPLETED steps, etc.

Just looking for some insight, as I've found this is the best place to go.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to ask the author of the generated report what is its intent. Apart from that, one would expect the meaning of each column of `v$rman_status` to be described in [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2149.htm#REFRN30306).

I've been working with Oracle since before `rman` existed, and I've never had a need to look at `v$rman_status`.  I look at the logs from my daily backup jobs.  Besides telling me IF there was a problem, it will shed light on what the problem was.  Much more useful than some report that simply says 'failed' or 'succeeded'.

All of my `rman` jobs capture the run-time logging by simply redirecting standard output to a file.  Then all you have to do is quickly scan the file for any ORA- or RMAN- errors.  If you've never looked at `rman` standard output, you would do well to look through the entire file for a few days just to get a feel for what's there.

If there is anything out of the ordinary that I do, it would be that I specify the name of the redirected log file to include the day of the week (`proddb_bkup_TUE.log`) so that I always have the last 7 days available. I then have a `cmd` script on my workstation that I run every morning to gather up the logs from all servers and scan them for 'ora-' and 'rman-' and report any hits.